# Как получать значении X, Y, Z?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

У меня есть NSString (Ts:1039 X:  371,00 (dps) Y: -651,00 (dps) Z: -504,00 (dps)) и мне получать отдельно каждый значении X, Y, Z

Comment: Ви можете конвертнуть вашу NSString в NSArray, пример по ссилке [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712551/how-to-convert-string-to-array-in-objective-c)

Comment: У меня не так получилось, можете мне показать

Comment: Просто там есть  двоеточие

Comment: Ви можете удалить двоеточие, yourString = [stringFromArray stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":;" withString:@""];

Comment: Если вам не трудно покажите мне код,  Я просто начинающии

Comment: Можете уточнить какой, я написал как удалить?

Comment: Нет полный ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *yourString = @"Hi how are you";
NSArray *arrayString = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSString *getAre = [arrayString objectAtIndex:2]; 

getAre = [stringFromArray stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
```

Я не проверял но должно работать.